# Swagger for Rails: how to describe complex parameters of request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, swagger, ruby-grape

When I use swagger for grape I can describe complex params:

params[:by_commentable][:commentable_id]
params[:by_commentable][:commentable_type]

```
desc "Get a list of comments"
  params do
     group :by_commentable do
       requires :commentable_id, type: Integer, desc: "Filter by: Commentable object ID"
       requires :commentable_type, type: String, desc: "Filter by: Commentable object type"
     end
     paginatable_params.call Comment
    end
    get "", http_codes: standard_responses do
      apply_scopes(Comment.order_recent).page(params[:page]).per_page(params[:per_page])
    end
   end
  end
```

How to do the same in Rails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, it is work:

```
swagger_api :index do
  param :query, :by_text, :string, :optional, 'By Text'
  param :query, 'listing[id]', :integer, :optional, 'Id'
end
```

Thanks!